# trying to create/delete multiple assocations with checkboxes and has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes

Here's what my models look like. A user has many channels they can subscribe to based on their group (User HABTM Group HABTM Channel) as well as channels they have subscribed to (User HM channels T subscriptions, I didn't use HABTM here because subscriptions will have a display order column).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :channels, through: :subscriptions
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :channels
end

class Channel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :channel
end
```

What I've done is display a list of all channels a user can subscribe to (if there's a simpler way to do this with only one SQL statement let me know):

```
@channels = Channel.joins(
  'JOIN channels_groups ON channels.id = channels_groups.channel_id', 
  'JOIN groups_users ON channels_groups.group_id = groups_users.group_id', 
  'JOIN users ON groups_users.user_id = users.id'
).where('users.id = ?', @user.id).uniq
```

What I can't figure out is how to create a form of checkboxes around this list of channels. Ideally, I'd like to be able to

1. create those subscriptions that the user checked off if they don't
   exist,
2. and remove those subscriptions that the user unchecked if
   they exist.

Is this a nested attributes form thing?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this. Think it can be improved?

In my view:

```
<% for channel in @channels do %>
  <%= check_box_tag "subscription[][channel_id]", channel.id, @user.channels.include?(channel) %>
  <%= channel.name %>
<% end %>

<%= hidden_field_tag "subscription[][channel_id]", "" %>
<%= submit_tag %>
```

Then in my controller:

```
# get all of a users subscriptions that weren't checked and delete them
@user.subscriptions.where('channel_id IN (?)', @user.channel_ids - params[:subscription].map{ |s| s['channel_id'].to_i }.flatten).delete_all
# then add all those that were checked
Subscription.create(params[:subscription]) { |s| s.user_id = @user.id }
```